# An in-built function to draw a torus in opengl glut

Tags: opengl

I am using opengl and I was wondering if there was an inbuilt function in opengl to draw a torus?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [glutSolidTorus](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node84.html).

Answer (score 1):

3lectrologos is right that a torus is available in Glut.

But if you only need the torus, you can just grab the code from [here](http://freeglut.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/freeglut/trunk/freeglut/freeglut/src/freeglut_geometry.c?view=markup) (from line 687).

[freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) is a completely OpenSourced alternative to the OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) library.